# insert into Database on every EditInPlace In JQuery

Tags: jquery

How to insert into database on every editInplace in JQuery..

```
               <script type="text/javascript">
                   var increment = 0;
        $(document).ready(function(){
                       $(".menu a").click(function () {
                        increment++;
   $("<div> Label </div>").appendTo(".menu li").addClass("div" + increment);
                 $(".div" + increment).show(function () {
           $(".div" + increment).editInPlace({
                url: "./server",
                show_buttons: true
                    });//editinplace

                         });//show
               });//click
            });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to insert into a database with Jquery is to use Jquery to call on a page which has some other code on it, that can easily insert into a database.

The most common way to do this is to use PHP and Jquery's post/get/ajax features to call on a page that has the PHP code used to insert into the database.

Answer (score 2):

You can't insert into a database using only JQuery. You must use AJAX to send the data to the server and then, there, insert into the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use asp.net page methods to handle the ajax request from edit-in-place and handle pushing info into database in that method. I'm doing this in my current project and it is really a charm for user, because they don't have to refresh whole page for small changes!!!